# Binding Image Source with Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I'm working on a custom control. This custom control has an image in it like this:

```
 <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Poster}" />
```

In my C# file, the `DependencyProperty` is the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PosterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Poster), 
    typeof(ImageSource), 
    typeof(MovieButton), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public ImageSource Poster
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(PosterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PosterProperty, value); }
}
```

Now I can add the following to my user control in XAML: `Poster="Images/NoPoster.png"` or `Poster = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/NoPoster.png"))` from code.

Everything is working fine. What I'm wondering is, why can't I declare `Poster` as `BitmapImage` or `string` instead of `ImageSource`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course declare it as `BitmapImage`. But that would be an unnecessary restriction, because the base class `ImageSource` is sufficient.

You can also use `string` or `Uri` as property type, but then you should replace the TemplateBinding by a regular Binding, because source and target property types no longer match, and built-in automatic type conversion should take place:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Poster, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

Note that you do not need an explicit binding converter, because type conversion is performed automatically by the `ImageSourceConverter` class, which is registered as type converter for `ImageSource`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your example is indeed working and what I was after in the first place. I think setting a string is less work than converting it to an `Uri` first and then to a `BitmapImage`. What would you suggest and is the more used method though?

Comment: `string` is of course sufficient. You may however want to take advantage of the validity checks performed by the `Uri` class. Users of your control would get an exception when they try to pass an invalid URI. Not a bad thing to have.

Comment: I know this is starting to get a little bit off-topic but, what do you mean with `Uri` validity checks?

Comment: As said, users of your control would get an exception when they try to pass an invalid image URI. That wouldn't happen with string.